# Why does jQuery param() encode these values differently?

Tags: jquery

I've noticed that when I pass an array of strings to jQuery's param(), the encoded string contains the object member name with an encoded subscript operator but no specified index. Example:

```
var stringA = "The First String";
var stringB = "The Second String";

alert($.param( { pars: [stringA, stringB] } ));
```

this produces the value: *pars%5B%5D=The+First+String&pars%5B%5D=The+Second+String*

However, if I pass an array of dates, the *pars* member is emitted with a subscript operator and an index, as though param() is attempting to instruct receivers of a particular order to the array elements. Example:

```
var dateA = new Date();
var dateB = new Date();

alert($.param( { pars: [dateA, dateA] } ));
```

This produces the value: *pars%5B0%5D=Thu+Apr+10+06%3A50%3A39+PDT+2014&pars%5B1%5D=Thu+Apr+10+06%3A50%3A39+PDT+2014*

Note the inclusion of an index inside each encoded subscript literal (i.e. pars[0], instead of pars[] in the first example).

Why does param() behave this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because a date has an object type, where as a string does not.

Objects can contain multiple values. Consider the below example from the param documentation:

```
$.param({ a: { b: 1, c: 2 }, d: [ 3, 4, { e: 5 } ] });
// "a[b]=1&a[c]=2&d[]=3&d[]=4&d[2][e]=5"
```

As you can see, all the primitives don't have their indices in the encoded result. Objects do.

This makes sense, because a primitive only has one value, which needs to be encoded, whereas objects can have multiple. Working from the above example:

```
$.param({ a: { b: 1, c: 2 }, d: [ 3, 4, { e: 5, f: 6 } ] });
// "a[b]=1&a[c]=2&d[]=3&d[]=4&d[2][e]=5&d[2][f]=6"

// Consider how this is different from:
$.param({ a: { b: 1, c: 2 }, d: [ 3, 4, { e: 5 }, { f: 6 } ] });
// "a[b]=1&a[c]=2&d[]=3&d[]=4&d[2][e]=5&d[3][f]=6"
```

The decoding function needs to be able to differentiate between `d[2]` and `d[3]`, but we don't really care about differentiating between the primitive's indices.

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/